# Get all cached and uncached views in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using `getChildCount()` method of the `RecyclerView` class to get the views in it but by this method I can see only those that are visible in the screen. I want to get all the list items that I have passed on to the adapter. How to achieve that?

Comment: add a public method to return the list used, like a getter function

Comment: get  clicked item postion , then  list.get(position) or define a Inteface in adapter when cilck item ->get params

Comment: I don't want the list used. I want the views in the recyclerView.

Comment: You need `getItemCount()` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemCount() )

Comment: Thank you @IshitaSinha. Could you please suggest me how to traverse the views in a loop?

Comment: Your question is unclear. [getItemCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemCount()) returns the number of items in the adapter, but you are talking about views. Since the recyclerView recycles it's views, you will (depending on the number of items) not be able to get the same amount of views as you have items.

Comment: As @AljoSt said, a `RecyclerView` recycles its views and it only has the visible number of items + ~2 views inflated at a time. When you scroll, the inflated views that go out of visibility are reused for the new items. So you cannot get inflated views for all the items passed on to the adapter. You can only get a subsection of items of visible items + ~2 items.

Comment: Okay, let me make my question clear. I can only get the Views that are on the screen by RecyclerView. How many views are on the screen can be found by getChildCount(). But I want to get all the items in the adapter, which as you have said through `getItemCount()`. Also I want references to all the Views in the adapter. If `getItemCount()` returns 10, then I want references to 10 views. Sorry, if my question was a bit unclear.

Comment: The whole concept of a RecylcerView is only to have as many Views inflated as is necessary to display the currently visible items. Imagin you had 1000 items in your RecyclerView Adapter. You don't want to have 1000 Views be inflated at one time. If you explain why you want a reference to the Views, we might be able to show you another way to accomplish what you want to do.